# Create Rush Hour function from numeric hours

Tags: r

I'm currently working on a problem where I have a column called hr (hours) which is numeric and lists hours from 0:23. What I would like to do is create another characterized column that gives "Yes" if hours are between 16 and 18 (rush hour) and "No" for all other times. I then want to tally up how many registered bike users (registered) there are during these times. I have tried the following code below however it does not give the desired output. I have also attached an image of my full dataframe. Any help would be appreciated and apologies if question is worded poorly as I am new to R and the StackOverflow community

```
bike_df %>%
 filter(hr > 15 | hr < 19) %>%
  tally(bike_df$registered)
```

[image: dataframe snapshot]

Comment: You can use `case_when`
`bike_df %>% mutate(ex = case_when(hr>15 & hr<19 ~ "yes",
                                                                  hr<15 & hr>19 ~ "no"))`

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options depending on whether you want the output summarised or not:

(`%>%` may be used instead of `|>`.)

```r
library(tidyverse)

bike_df <- tribble(
  ~hr, ~registered,
  15, 100,
  15, 101,
  16, 200,
  16, 201,
  18, 300,
  18, 301,
  20, 400,
) 

# Summarised
bike_df |> 
  mutate(rush_hour = if_else(between(hr, 16, 18), "Yes", "No")) |> 
  group_by(rush_hour) |> 
  summarise(registered = sum(registered))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   rush_hour registered
#>   <chr>          <dbl>
#> 1 No               601
#> 2 Yes             1002

# Unsummarised
bike_df |> 
  mutate(rush_hour = if_else(between(hr, 16, 18), "Yes", "No")) |> 
  add_count(rush_hour, wt = registered, name = "rush_reg")
#> # A tibble: 7 × 4
#>      hr registered rush_hour rush_reg
#>   <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>
#> 1    15        100 No             601
#> 2    15        101 No             601
#> 3    16        200 Yes           1002
#> 4    16        201 Yes           1002
#> 5    18        300 Yes           1002
#> 6    18        301 Yes           1002
#> 7    20        400 No             601
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>